# Trump's presidential record to denounce Russia for wrongdoing

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, intelligence

How many different instances has Trump been defiant to denounce (or sanction) Russia regarding Russian wrongdoing related to US national security (and intelligence) that we know about in the public eye since he's been POTUS?

For example, currently he is being silent (or blaming other countries) for the cyberattacks the US intelligence says they have proof tracing it back to Russia that his own Secretary of State and Attorney General publicly say they agree with the US intelligence reports yet he refuses to denounce Russia himself in public.

Does anyone know how many different instances of such Russian wrongdoing since he's been in office he has refused to agree with others in the US intelligence community or his cabinet and such to sanction or publicly denounce Russia?

### Potential Objective Measures (but not limited to)

- The US intelligence community and/or the administration's cabinet publicly denouncing
- Others providing evidence of Russian wrongdoing
- Issues that other NATO members have responded with regard to Russia

### Notable Items

Many people believe there is a reason why Trump will not denounce Russia for wrongdoing. It doesn't take too much research or effort to find notable claims as such which I've included just a few of those with lots of detail below.

- [All of Trump’s Russia Ties, in 7 Charts](https://www.politico.com/magazine/story/2017/03/connections-trump-putin-russia-ties-chart-flynn-page-manafort-sessions-214868)
- [Business projects of Donald Trump in Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_projects_of_Donald_Trump_in_Russia)
- [Following the Money: Trump and Russia-Linked Transactions From the Campaign to the Presidential Inauguration](https://www.americanprogress.org/issues/democracy/reports/2018/12/17/464235/following-the-money/)
- [Trump’s Russian connections](https://ig.ft.com/sites/trumps-russian-connections/)

Comment: Let me know how I can fix this if there's something wrong with it please. Just comment me and I'll give it a good try.

Comment: I'm concerned that answering this question requires making a judgement call about which Russian actions counted as wrongdoing and deserved a response. Is there an objective measure that fits the spirit of the question?

Comment: What about the part being in there that others in the US intelligence community and his cabinet agreeing with the finding of such US intelligence reports being what you seek with this respect? Is that not enough alone? I may not fully understand clearly what objective measure is so I may need kicked a few times to better get that.

Comment: That's a good start, but perhaps it could be more precise. I feel that there's a line somewhere between widespread consensus and the opinion of a few individuals, and that we should be on the same page about where to draw it.

Comment: @AlphaDraconis instances where at least the leaders if at least X other countries have spoken out and Trump did not?

Comment: @AlphaDraconis: Someone could compare e.g. with issues that other NATO members have responded to in re Russia. But that may underestimate the occurrences because some things may have affected mainly the US, so the rest of NATO may not have had much reason to "argue over Trump's head" about therm...

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this article answers the question perfectly — and it was written on August 4, 2020, so it misses the Russian hacking incident and anything else in the last 5 months of the year — but it's a good start.

[CNN: 37 times Trump was soft on Russia](https://www.cnn.com/2019/11/17/politics/trump-soft-on-russia/index.html)

That's roughly once every five weeks during Trump's term.